# Запятые при пояснении

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, пояснительные

> Республика Саха, или(,) как её еще называют(,) Якутия...

Должны ли в скобках стоять запятые? В НКРЯ в подобных конструкциях есть различные варианты постановки знаков препинания.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Республика Саха, или(,) как её еще называют(,) Якутия...

Здесь "как её еще называют" — вводное предложение; обычно такие предложения выделяются запятыми.

Возможные варианты пунктуационного оформления:

*Республика Саха, или, как её еще называют, Якутия, <...*>

*Республика Саха (или, как её еще называют, Якутия) <...>*

Answer (score 2):

*Как её еще называют* — это вводное предложение.
Вводные предложения имеют значения, близкие к значениям вводных слов и сочетаний. Они выделяются запятыми, либо, значительно реже, – знаком тире.

*Или Якутия* — это пояснение.
Если союз «или» присоединяет пояснительную конструкцию, обозначающую одно и то же понятие другими словами, то перед ним ставится запятая.

Запятая после союза «или» ставится, если вводное предложение можно опустить или переставить в другое место предложения без нарушения его структуры.
В части предложения такие передвижки возможны (*Республика Саха, или Якутия, как её еще называют...*).
Это означает, что «как её еще называют» необходимо выделить запятыми.

**Республика Саха, или, как её еще называют, Якутия...**

> В этой книге рассказывается о сказочной стране, в которой жили малыши и малышки, то есть крошечные мальчики и девочки, **или, как их иначе называли, коротышки**.
> Н. Носов. Незнайка в Солнечном городе

[Запятые при вводных словах с распространением](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85_%D1%81_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/)